# UbuntuStudio 20.04 meta installer gone?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio, metapackages

I tried Ubuntu Studio 20.04 in a VM to prep for migration. As I installed I kept waiting for the package selection dialog I've always seen to pop up but it never did. I installed thinking maybe on first login? Nope...I poked around and found the meta installer thing which only gave me an option to install branding but never to choose if I was setting up for Audio, Video, Photography, Design, etc. It just installed EVERYTHING.

Is this a bug? Oversight? -or is this actually a design decision to just install every bit of cruft possible no matter what the intended use is? -Asking for a friend...

Comment: I had to edit your question to unlock the upvote button, hope it's ok for you. If not, feel free to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a design decision.
The [UbuntuStudio Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio) states:

```
Changes for this release (compared to 19.10 Eoan Ermine)

    The package/metapackage selection screen has been removed from the Ubiquity
    (live session) installer due to a bug which caused unwanted packages to be
    removed.
```

The only option to choose desired components I see at the moment is to use the [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) which can be used after installing any other official flavour of Ubuntu (see http://ubuntustudio.org/download/). Many users seem to prefer the plasma desktop (Kubuntu) which will be default in 20.10 (see http://ubuntustudio.org/news/)

Comment: Clear as mud. Which is to say I checked the notes and info on the ubu studio website, heaven forbid they post that there. I can't say I agree with "clearly states" unless you know or think to look on a different website for the info. Either way good to know and sad they yanked it rather than fixed it.

Comment: @nPHYN1T3 Please remind that many linux distributions are maitained by volunteers, enthusiasts. Due to limited manpower and time it happens that a bug cannot be fixed until release date of a distribution, in such a case removing the package is the only solution. We all have to live with that. UbuntuStudio is not a commercial product, complaining doesn't help much, if you can, contribute...

Comment: I remember that just fine but one of the core tenants is documenting your code and release notes. More so this isn't me being angry, just saying it was not clearly stated in the appropriate place. If they had even a tiny blurb about "check here for dif's or changes" with a link that would have explained things. Again, not angry, just saying as per your original answer you can say the release notes "clearly state" this but there is no where on the site that "clearly states" the release notes were on another website. :P

Comment: Don't forget the whole reason I asked here is while reading the help/docs it says for other questions/things not covered/support to ask here, so I did. Not angry, just trying to figure out there the meta installer went so I don't have to kitchen sink an install.

Comment: @nPHYN1T3 It's fine, it's not my code, I'm just a UbuntuStudio user. If I open http://ubuntustudio.org/ I see a big, fat `DOWNLOAD` button and beside it a `RELEASE NOTES` button, same size. But one can overlook this. The only option I see at the moment is to use the [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) which can be used with any official flavour of Ubuntu (see http://ubuntustudio.org/download/). Many users seem to prefer to use the plasma desktop (Kubuntu) which will be default in 20.10 (see http://ubuntustudio.org/news/)

Answer (score 0):

You still can install Ubuntu Studio using [metapackages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/ubuntustudio-meta):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-desktop
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio-core
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio-plugins
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-fonts
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-graphics
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-photography
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-publishing
#sudo apt install ubuntustudio-video
```

or tasks:

> ```
>  $ sudo apt-get install tasksel
>  ...
>  $ tasksel --list-tasks | grep studio
>  u ubuntustudio-dvd-live  Ubuntu Studio live DVD
>  u ubuntustudio-audio Audio recording and editing suite
>  u ubuntustudio-desktop   Ubuntu Studio desktop
>  u ubuntustudio-desktop-core  Ubuntu Studio minimal DE installation
>  u ubuntustudio-fonts Large selection of font packages
>  u ubuntustudio-graphics  2D/3D creation and editing suite
>  u ubuntustudio-photography   Photograph touchup and editing suite
>  u ubuntustudio-publishing    Publishing applications
>  u ubuntustudio-video Video creation and editing suite
> ```

with commands like

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio^
```

Comment: This is rather opposite to my question. I don't want to install things, I want to DEselect things. The point is I only want what I want, not everything. UbuStu used to have a package selection on install so you could select what you want. Now this *seems* to be gone and you are forced to just let it shotgun everything you don't need or want onto the system. I've tried in past releases to remove things post install which only led to the system becoming a broken mess.

Comment: (I can't add a damned new line!) I checked the UbuStu site and it said nothing about the meta being removed. All the things I can find in the docs still says it's there (which it is) but lacks any option other than the "branding." Sadly as usual the docs are outdated and it says to "ask here" for support.